# SSD stuck on read-only mode

Tags: partition, ssd, ntfs, readonly, smart

I bought a second hand SSD. I made tests before buying it.

When I got the disc, I ran its tests. I did low scan with HDTune. There was no error. The writing speed was also fine. I trusted and bought it.   I installed Windows 10, Linux Mint (Cinnamon) and Ubuntu. I also moved my data from my previous disk because I trusted the SSD.

I've observed obvious acceleration on my computer. I used it for two or three days without any problems. But then my computer started giving "SMART Hard Disk Error 301" error. And then Windows could not boot.

I removed the disk from the computer and booted my computer from my old disk. Then I tried to connect the SSD externally and recover my data. First, NTFS partitions were seen as RAW on Windows. And I wanted to recover my data on Linux. I turned on the computer with the Ubuntu Live Disk and accessed the disks. I copied the data back to my old disk without any problem. The point I want to draw your attention to here is that "**I could not move my data, I copied it**".

The disk suddenly switched to a read-only structure or mode. Now I can't write anything to the disk, I can't delete it, I can only read it. Below, I write item by item a few things I experienced about the disc and applied to fix it.

- I can boot the Linux (Mint and Ubuntu) installed on the disk without any problems. I cannot start Windows. Windows stays on black screen after boot screen. (I had installed Ubuntu last. I can choose Mint, Ubuntu, Windows from Ubuntu's GRUB.)
- I can't delete any partitions on disk. The methods I applied;

  - When I right click> delete partition from Windows Disk Management, I delete the partition, and it comes back a few seconds later.
  - I am trying to delete the partition with "-" button by selecting the partition in the "disks" application in Linux. The partitions were deleted and then comes back when the application scans the disks after applying the changes.
  - On Windows, I do "attributes disk clear readonly" with "diskpart" application, then I do "select disk x, select part y, delete part override". All commands are completed successfully, but the partitions are coming back again.
  - I boot the machine with GParted live disk, delete all partitions. It says succesfully completed, but the same partitions come back when it scans the disks. (again and again)
- I am writing data to the drive. The writing speed is fine. (60-70-100 MB/sec) I am writing a 30 GB file. The data I have written is lost when I eject and re-plug the disc.
- I am erasing data from the disk. The data I deleted with Shift + Delete comes back to the disk. It deletes files. The progress bar fills while deleting process and successfully completes it.
- I rename any folder, the name reverts back to the old one.
- I have used partition deletion as well as other partition software such as Aomei, MiniTool Partition Wizard, Eauseus,TestDisk etc. but I could not get any successful result.

By the way, I got the SMART error several times in the beginning, it doesn't give this error now.

Although I have done so many partition deletions, I can still open the installed Ubuntu and Mint on the disk.
When I scan the disk with HDTune, no errors appear. The whole disk is still green in low scan.
I do not get any errors in my processes, all the changes I want to make on the disk are completed, but it returns to its previous state.

I say read-only, but it's not exactly readonly. Because this is not normal read-only. Read only gives error on write attempt. He asks for no permission. This is stuck at a point and cannot go back or forward from that point.

I am not trying to save this disk and I don't want to use this drive. I cannot trust it anymore. I just want to solve this issue. It may help not only to me but anyone encounters this kind of problem.

Do you have any ideas to force this drive to format, delete partition etc.?

Thank you for all anwers.

Comment: _I am writing data to the drive. The writing speed is fine. (60-70-100 MB/sec) I am writing a 30 GB file. The data I have written is lost when I eject and re-plug the disc._  This means the data isn't being written to the disk at all.  I've seen this failure mode with SD cards as well.  The disk is toast.

Comment: Isn't there any solution for this?

Comment: I don't know for certain which is why I'm not creating an answer but I expect what happened here is that your bad sector count exceeded the maximum (based on spare tracks) and the drive went into readonly mode to protect the data.  After that it won't report SMART errors anymore as there is no point.